# I have a button that opens a GUI, how do I set where the GUI shows up on the screen?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window, location

I know of the action `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` which centers the GUI but i want it just off center as both my GUI's are the same size and i want the user to know that they have opened a new window, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`setLocationByPlatform(boolean locationByPlatform)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform(boolean)).

See [How to best position Swing GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7143287/597657) for a demo.

[image: setLocationByPlatform()]

Comment: +1.  Did you know it is possible to 'steal' images from one thread to another?  I right click on the image to copy the URL, then just dump it in an image tag in the other question or answer.  Something like `<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/D1JLb.png" alt="..">`.  I hope you don't mind me editing your answer, but a picture paints a thousand words, and I suspect that seeing the end result encourages people to follow the link.  :)